# All local hosts unreachable while connected to Wi-Fi

Tags: wifi

My Raspi is connected to our WLAN using the following `/etc/network/interfaces` settings

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    address 192.168.65.227
    netmask 255.255.254.0
    network 192.168.64.0
    broadcast 192.168.65.255
    gateway 192.168.65.254 
    dns-nameservers 192.168.65.21 192.168.65.11
```

And the following settings in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpc_supplicant.conf`

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB

network={
    ssid="<ssid>"
    psk="<psk>"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

With this config, **no hostnames** are resolved - I suspect because the Pi can't find my local DNS servers (192.168.65.21 and 192.168.65.11). If I change these in the network interfaces file to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 then **external hostnames** are resolved so I can successfully `ping google.com` (whereas previously only specifying the IP address -- e.g `ping 8.8.8.8` -- would work).

If I attempt to `ping` any local IP addresses, it tells me that the destination host is unreachable; internet works but not local network.

I am also unable to reach the Pi from other machines on my local network. My initial thought was an incorrect subnet mask, but when I run `ifconfig` it correctly brings through 255.255.254.0

Comment: Why do people pick these random settings and where do they come from?

Comment: What random settings?

Comment: @Milliways well that was an unhelpful comment, not what this site is about

Comment: I think the point is you seem to have done something [cargo cult style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and are then perplexed that it doesn't work.  *There actually is no question here,* but it's implicit what you more or less meant to ask is the duplicate.

Comment: I don't know why you'd assume that - I wrote this myself and I've set up networking on several Linux distros that have all worked. I included all of this information because I wanted to be clear, not because I don't understand how it works. On the same machine, for instance, eth0 works with a static IP. I think it would be helpful if @Milliways was more clear instead of just criticizing and marking as a duplicate of a generic question that doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: Just for the record I did not mark as duplicate, but "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: It says "marked as duplicate by Milliways, goldilocks"?

Comment: @Sinfieldd Did you disable the dhcp client daemon (`dhcpcd`)?  You must disable it if you want to use `/etc/interfaces`.